# ffmpeg rawvideo codec dropping frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture

I have an [EasyCap capture card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01H6OQI1W) and am trying to capture video from a Hi8 tape in a camcorder. The footage comes in at 25 FPS. When I try to capture using the `-c:v rawvideo` option, it captures at 25 FPS but I get some dropped frames. However, if I use the `-c:v copy` option, it captures at 50 FPS but doesn't drop any frames.

I'm confused about this behavior. Why are frames being dropped with the `-c:v rawvideo` option? And why does the `-c:v copy` option use 50 FPS? And so what is the correct why to capture the video from the camcorder?

---

### code and output

**using `-c:v rawvideo`**

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v rawvideo -t 00:01:00 a.avi
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 113727.197262, bitrate: 165888 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, 165888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to 'a.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, q=2-31, 165888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 rawvideo
frame= 1500 fps= 25 q=-0.0 Lsize= 1215049kB time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=165894.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 speed=   1x    
video:1215000kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.004058%
```

**using `-c:v copy`**

```bsh
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -t 00:01:00 a.avi
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 113835.003494, bitrate: 165888 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, 165888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, avi, to 'a.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 720x576, q=2-31, 165888 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1492 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1208613kB time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=165016.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
video:1208520kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.007716%
```

Comment: The logs show only 1 frame dropped with `rawvideo` and both commands run at 1x. The input is detected as 25 fps in both cases. However, the timescale with `copy` is double so video is playing at 2x speed. Save to MKV/MOV rather than AVI with `copy`.

Comment: Ah, that seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

As @Gyan mentioned in the comments, the video can be saved at the correct frame rate with the `-c:v copy` option by saving to a `.mkv` file rather than a `.avi`.

I'm still not sure why frames are being dropped with the `c:v rawvideo` option though...